# My Phone keeps on force closing!

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-versions

I have a my|phone brand phone. It's a filipino brand. Whenever i play games it just keep on going back to home menu. I tried shutting my phone down or just restart it so i can play and use my apps. But sometimes it doesnt work. It will just go back to home menu. Please help me solve this. Im not good at phones and such things. Thanks.

Comment: By '*filipino*' do you mean a brand from Philippines? And since "MyPhone"  is a brand itself which specific device of it are you using?

Comment: MyPhone Rio Grande.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running out of memory.  I would go to setting and in developer options, background limit, set that to at most 2. You have to set that after ever reboot, just so you know. Also in KK open your resent places and close/kill all those.    I recomend download an app called cooltool. It will display current available mem in status bar.    Hope that helps

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.cpuoverlay&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dcool+tools+play+store&pcampaignid=APPU_1_ItWOVZmEGoLpoATrr4CgBQ.      Sorry I'm a noob :)